# Height function for 3D drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3d

I've been drawing 2D features in 3D space using code like the following:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-0.2cm,-0.4cm)}, y={(1cm,0cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}]{
  \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=1]
    \draw[fill=blue,opacity=0.3] (0,0) circle (3cm);
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'd now like to distort the z-coordinate of the scope in which I am drawing. That is, instead of just drawing at height `z=1`, I'd like `z` to be a function of `x` and `y`.

Is this (relatively speaking) easily possible? If it helps, I think in the end all I'd like to have is something piecewise with `z = x^2` up to some fixed `x`, and then a constant value after that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to declare your own coordinate system. As Andrew says, you may want to make your example a bit more specific and complete, but here is something that tells you how that works.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\makeatletter 
\define@key{weirdkeys}{x}{\def\myx{#1}} 
\define@key{weirdkeys}{y}{\def\myy{#1}} 
\define@key{weirdkeys}{z}{\def\myz{#1}} 
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{weird}%
{%
\setkeys{weirdkeys}{#1}%
\pgfpointxyz{\myx}{\myy}{\myz+\myx*\myx}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-0.2cm,-0.4cm)}, y={(1cm,0cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}]
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\fill (weird cs:x=\X,y=\X,z=0) circle[radius=1pt];}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]